# Cause an reolution C# "Espression denotes a 'type parameter', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'type' was expected" 

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code that produces a compilation issue in my C# generic function:

```
static void solve () {
    int[] vals = RA<int>();
}
```

and my RA function:

```
static T[] RA<T> () {
    return Console.ReadLine ().Split ().Select (v => T.Parse (v)).ToArray ();
}
```

Giving me the following error:

```
Espression denotes a 'type parameter', 
where a 'variable', 'value' or 'type' was expected
```

Can the community assist me in debugging or understanding this issue and resolving it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do with that expression chain?

Comment: @linkerro I need to read one line from file with numbers. Somewhere numbers are doubles, somewhere - integers etc. So I want to create ONE method for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler don't know a result type in compilation time and can't link Parse call.

You should use Convert class to avoid compilation issue and limit generic type attribute

```
static T[] RA<T>()
    where T : IConvertible
{
    return RL().Split().Select(v => (T)Convert.ChangeType(v, typeof(T))).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to rethink this - you can't call static methods on a type parameter. For one thing, the compiler has no way of resolving them at compile-time. See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/14/calling-static-methods-on-type-parameters-is-illegal-part-one.aspx) for more details.

You might want to change it to something like:

```
static T[] RA<T>(Func<string, T> projection)
{
    return RL().Split().Select(projection).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: RL() means Console.ReadLine()

Comment: @YatsukoYin: Why didn't you just include `Console.ReadLine()` then? Why introduce a confusing name for no reason?

Comment: @YatsukoYin With Jon's function you can just call it like `RA(int.Parse)` or `RA(double.Parse)`

Comment: @YatsukoYin: So these are your *real* method and type names? `RA`, `RL` and `solve`? I would *strongly* urge you to think of whoever may come after you - write meaningful names and follow the .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet not real, this template I am using just when I am solving problems on acm.timus.ru, codeforces.com etc. 
so, dont worry =)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to replace `T.Parse (v)` with `System.Convert.ChangeType(v, typeof(T))`, but it can be dangerous in meaning of possible InvalidCastExceptions.

Comment: You also need to cast the result of `ChangeType` to `T`